# How do I make my plane appear 3D like in the "Roll-a-ball" tutorial?

Tags: unity

I am following [the first tutorial on the Unity website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial), which details making a 'Roll-a-ball' game.

I am stuck at a point where I need to make a 3D plane object; it looks flat, to me, and unlike how it looks like in the tutorial.

How do I make my plane look 3D?

---

This is what I see:

[image: Flat]

This is what I see in the tutorial:

[image: In the tutorial]

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to be _inclined_ w.r.t. the 'up' vector?

Comment: If you're asking how to change the camera angle in scene view: drag the cursor while holding the right mouse button.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I am not sure...I guess I meant the plane needs to look 3d? It looks really flat right now. I do not know if I made a mistake or the plane is fine but I am viewing it wrong.

Comment: @Peter, it does not appear to be an issue with the camera.

Comment: @Gnemlock, I did not know that. Thank you for editing my post.

Comment: @Krythic. I want it to look 3d as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you expect the result to look like? How would a "Plane" become 3D, and if it were to become 3D, would it be called a Plane anymore?

Comment: @Krythic, to be fair, "Plane" is listed under ***3D Objects***, in Unity. I think it is fairly obvious what the user expects to see, as they have given us an actual screenshot of *what they see* and *what they expect us to see*.

Comment: Reversing my vote, as if Unity *itself* lists a plane as a "3D Object", fair enough if a newbie does, too.

Comment: @Gnemlock Sure, that makes sense. Will remember for next time. Much gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your question, we need to start with some base understanding; planes *are* flat, by definition:

> plane
>
> 1. a **flat** surface on which a straight line joining any two points on it would wholly lie.
>
>    *"the horizontal plane"*
>
>    synonyms:   **flat surface**, level surface;
>
> <sub>- ["Plane" as defined by a quick Google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=define%20plane) (emphasis mine)</sub>

In fact, they only appear under "3D" in Unity because they are *rendered* in 3D space, using 3D drawing concepts. As a result, they look like flat lines, when viewed at from the side. *Exactly* as shown in your first screenshot.

---

In your screenshot, it appears your moving directly along the Z axis. It is most likely that you have initialised your Unity project in 2D, as opposed to 3D. Contrary to the answer provided by *lilotop*, there is no real reason to restart in 3D. Unity does not need to handle 2D and 3D across separate projects. There should only be two settings that need to be changed, for a new project.

[image: To change between 2D and 3D mode, select or deselect **2D** from the top left corner of the Scene view.]

When you start a 2D project, you will start in 2D mode, in the Scene view. This means that you will start off looking directly along the Z axis. It also means that <kbd>ALT + RMB</kbd> will *pan* the view. If we swap to 3D mode, in the Scene view, <kbd>ALT + RMB</kbd> will *rotate* the view, and let us see the plane in full 3D.

[image: In 3D mode, we can see the shape of the plane, rotate around our scene with the mouse and observe all 3 axis in the top right corner of the Scene view.]

If you truly did start your project in 2D mode, there is one last thing we need to do. The camera used to render your game to the screen will likely be set to *Orthographic*, to render the area as a 2D image. It needs to be set to *Perspective*, to render an area in 3D. You will likely have to play around with it to get the exact perspective you want; but playing around with it is the only real way to learn - and you will likely have to do so regardless of it's initial settings.

[image: The *Projection* setting of your Camera should be set to *Perspective* to render 3D images.]